# How to avoid overriding elements with other CSS files/classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have two different CSS codes (separate things) that both have `svg` and `path` elements in them. This is a problem since they both override each other. Is there a way to rename either one of the code differently, so that both CSS codes do not override each other?

This is my code for preloader that mostly have `svg` and `path` elements (renaming this code would just be hectic but I will just show incase):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');



.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #05f7f9;    
        }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
       fill: #05f7f9;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
    top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="svg-file z-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
      <g id="H">
        <path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z" fill="#47AF9A" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for skills section:

```css
.services .icon-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px 20px 80px 20px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 90px 0px rgba(110, 123, 131, 0.05);
}

.services .icon-box .icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

.services .icon-box .icon i {
  font-size: 36px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

.services .icon-box .icon svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.services .icon-box .icon svg path {
  transition: 0.5s;
  fill: #f5f5f5;
}

.services .icon-box h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.services .icon-box h4 a {
  color: #45505b;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

.services .icon-box p {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.services .icon-box:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.services .iconbox-blue i {
  color: #47aeff;
}

.services .iconbox-blue:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-blue:hover .icon path {
  fill: #47aeff;
}

.services .iconbox-orange i {
  color:rgb(92, 19, 160);
}

.services .iconbox-orange:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-orange:hover .icon path {
  fill: #4a2fc4;
}

.services .iconbox-pink i {
  color: #e80368;
}

.services .iconbox-pink:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-pink:hover .icon path {
  fill: #e80368;
}

.services .iconbox-yellow i {
  color: #ffbb2c;
}

.services .iconbox-yellow:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-yellow:hover .icon path {
  fill: #ffbb2c;
}

.services .iconbox-red i {
  color: #ff5828;
}

.services .iconbox-red:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-red:hover .icon path {
  fill: #ff5828;
}

.services .iconbox-teal i {
  color: #11dbcf;
}

.services .iconbox-teal:hover .icon i {
  color: #fff;
}

.services .iconbox-teal:hover .icon path {
  fill: #11dbcf;
}
```

```html
<section id="services" class="services">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Skills</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,521.0016835830174C376.1290562159157,517.8887921683347,466.0731472004068,529.7835943286574,510.70327084640275,468.03025145048787C554.3714126377745,407.6079735673963,508.03601936045806,328.9844924480964,491.2728898941984,256.3432110539036C474.5976632858925,184.082847569629,479.9380746630129,96.60480741107993,416.23090153303,58.64404602377083C348.86323505073057,18.502131276798302,261.93793281208167,40.57373210992963,193.5410806939664,78.93577620505333C130.42746243093433,114.334589627462,98.30271207620316,179.96522072025542,76.75703585869454,249.04625023123273C51.97151888228291,328.5150500222984,13.704378332031375,421.85034740162234,66.52175969318436,486.19268352777647C119.04800174914682,550.1803526380478,217.28368757567262,524.383925680826,300,521.0016835830174"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-code-curly"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Java</h4>
              <p>Java is my main programming language to use, as I am proficient in it. I mainly use this language for my side projects <i>(check this website frequently to see a portfolio of my projects!)</i> I have an extensive knowledge in this language, which is why I started to post tutorial videos on <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCU19anfnmqNvt4BRN9EQ4GQ">YT</a> for anyone who would like to learn it! </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-md-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-orange ">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,582.0697525312426C382.5290701553225,586.8405444964366,449.9789794690241,525.3245884688669,502.5850820975895,461.55621195738473C556.606425686781,396.0723002908107,615.8543463187945,314.28637112970534,586.6730223649479,234.56875336149918C558.9533121215079,158.8439757836574,454.9685369536778,164.00468322053177,381.49747125262974,130.76875717737553C312.15926192815925,99.40240125094834,248.97055460311594,18.661163978235184,179.8680185752513,50.54337015887873C110.5421016452524,82.52863877960104,119.82277516462835,180.83849132639028,109.12597500060166,256.43424936330496C100.08760227029461,320.3096726198365,92.17705696193138,384.0621239912766,124.79988738764834,439.7174275375508C164.83382741302287,508.01625554203684,220.96474134820875,577.5009287672846,300,582.0697525312426"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-command"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>C++</h4>
              <p>Currently learning C++ through CodeAcademy and implementing the knowledge onto small and basic side-projects. I hope to use this as on of my main programming languages, later on!</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4 mt-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-pink">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,541.5067337569781C382.14930387511276,545.0595476570109,479.8736841581634,548.3450877840088,526.4010558755058,480.5488172755941C571.5218469581645,414.80211281144784,517.5187510058486,332.0715597781072,496.52539010469104,255.14436215662573C477.37192572678356,184.95920475031193,473.57363656557914,105.61284051026155,413.0603344069578,65.22779650032875C343.27470386102294,18.654635553484475,251.2091493199835,5.337323636656869,175.0934190732945,40.62881213300186C97.87086631185822,76.43348514350839,51.98124368387456,156.15599469081315,36.44837278890362,239.84606092416172C21.716077023791087,319.22268207091537,43.775223500013084,401.1760424656574,96.891909868211,461.97329694683043C147.22146801428983,519.5804099606455,223.5754009179313,538.201503339737,300,541.5067337569781"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-code-alt"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>HTML/CSS/Javascript</h4>
              <p>Self-taught HTML/CSS/JS as I thought it would be a fun experience to try web development. I am now at the stage of designing websites from scratch and using it for my side-projects. My first ever website using HTML/CSS/JS when I was a complete beginner can be viewed <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href = "https://hussainomer1.github.io/Hussainblog.github.io/">here</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-yellow">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,503.46388370962813C374.79870501325706,506.71871716319447,464.8034551963731,527.1746412648533,510.4981551193396,467.86667711651364C555.9287308511215,408.9015244558933,512.6030010748507,327.5744911775523,490.211057578863,256.5855673507754C471.097692560561,195.9906835881958,447.69079081568157,138.11976852964426,395.19560036434837,102.3242989838813C329.3053358748298,57.3949838291264,248.02791733380457,8.279543830951368,175.87071277845988,42.242879143198664C103.41431057327972,76.34704239035025,93.79494320519305,170.9812938413882,81.28167332365135,250.07896920659033C70.17666984294237,320.27484674793965,64.84698225790005,396.69656628748305,111.28512138212992,450.4950937839243C156.20124167950087,502.5303643271138,231.32542653798444,500.4755392045468,300,503.46388370962813"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-brain"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Growth Mindset</h4>
              <p>I have always found myself growing outside my comfort zone and taking on new challenges that facilitate my personal growth. This is skill that I continue to work on, as you can never fully equip this skill but strengthen it, each time.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-red">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,503.46388370962813C374.79870501325706,506.71871716319447,464.8034551963731,527.1746412648533,510.4981551193396,467.86667711651364C555.9287308511215,408.9015244558933,512.6030010748507,327.5744911775523,490.211057578863,256.5855673507754C471.097692560561,195.9906835881958,447.69079081568157,138.11976852964426,395.19560036434837,102.3242989838813C329.3053358748298,57.3949838291264,248.02791733380457,8.279543830951368,175.87071277845988,42.242879143198664C103.41431057327972,76.34704239035025,93.79494320519305,170.9812938413882,81.28167332365135,250.07896920659033C70.17666984294237,320.27484674793965,64.84698225790005,396.69656628748305,111.28512138212992,450.4950937839243C156.20124167950087,502.5303643271138,231.32542653798444,500.4755392045468,300,503.46388370962813"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-file-find"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Opportunity Seeker</h4>
              <p>If you are on the path to do something incredible either for your own benefit or the community as a whole, you will find yourself seeking opportunities whenever you possibly can. Seeking an opportunity becomes a part of you and you find yourself instinctively taking on challenges to make a postive impact on your world</p>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,503.46388370962813C374.79870501325706,506.71871716319447,464.8034551963731,527.1746412648533,510.4981551193396,467.86667711651364C555.9287308511215,408.9015244558933,512.6030010748507,327.5744911775523,490.211057578863,256.5855673507754C471.097692560561,195.9906835881958,447.69079081568157,138.11976852964426,395.19560036434837,102.3242989838813C329.3053358748298,57.3949838291264,248.02791733380457,8.279543830951368,175.87071277845988,42.242879143198664C103.41431057327972,76.34704239035025,93.79494320519305,170.9812938413882,81.28167332365135,250.07896920659033C70.17666984294237,320.27484674793965,64.84698225790005,396.69656628748305,111.28512138212992,450.4950937839243C156.20124167950087,502.5303643271138,231.32542653798444,500.4755392045468,300,503.46388370962813"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-user-pin"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Leadership</h4>
              <p>I take upon a leadership role whenever I get a chance such as school clubs or other organizatons, where I have the role of organizing events/activities while also contributing to the organizational success.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-orange">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,503.46388370962813C374.79870501325706,506.71871716319447,464.8034551963731,527.1746412648533,510.4981551193396,467.86667711651364C555.9287308511215,408.9015244558933,512.6030010748507,327.5744911775523,490.211057578863,256.5855673507754C471.097692560561,195.9906835881958,447.69079081568157,138.11976852964426,395.19560036434837,102.3242989838813C329.3053358748298,57.3949838291264,248.02791733380457,8.279543830951368,175.87071277845988,42.242879143198664C103.41431057327972,76.34704239035025,93.79494320519305,170.9812938413882,81.28167332365135,250.07896920659033C70.17666984294237,320.27484674793965,64.84698225790005,396.69656628748305,111.28512138212992,450.4950937839243C156.20124167950087,502.5303643271138,231.32542653798444,500.4755392045468,300,503.46388370962813"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-male"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Interpersonal</h4>
              <p>This is a skill I developed through my work experience and through my time working for welfare organizations that allowed me to interact with customers on a daily basis. Resolving customer complaints, working at a cashier, and in-store customer service are all some of the key roles that allowed me to strengthen my interpersonal skills</p>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch mt-4" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="icon-box iconbox-pink">
              <div class="icon">
                <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5" d="M300,503.46388370962813C374.79870501325706,506.71871716319447,464.8034551963731,527.1746412648533,510.4981551193396,467.86667711651364C555.9287308511215,408.9015244558933,512.6030010748507,327.5744911775523,490.211057578863,256.5855673507754C471.097692560561,195.9906835881958,447.69079081568157,138.11976852964426,395.19560036434837,102.3242989838813C329.3053358748298,57.3949838291264,248.02791733380457,8.279543830951368,175.87071277845988,42.242879143198664C103.41431057327972,76.34704239035025,93.79494320519305,170.9812938413882,81.28167332365135,250.07896920659033C70.17666984294237,320.27484674793965,64.84698225790005,396.69656628748305,111.28512138212992,450.4950937839243C156.20124167950087,502.5303643271138,231.32542653798444,500.4755392045468,300,503.46388370962813"></path>
                </svg>
                <i class="bx bx-world"></i>
              </div>
              <h4>Street Smart</h4>
              <p>From interacting with people, and developing positive relationships with them, I am able to further strenghthen this skill, as it only develops through having different perspectives of life. For instance, being able to withstand tough situations or knowing what others may be thinking in a particular scenario are all examples of street smarts.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
```

This skills section code may look very long, but this code's CSS only has `SVG` and `path` only like 2 times, and renaming this would be easier than renaming all the instances of `SVG` and `path` in the above code. Both of the CSS files or codes collide with each other, as both have `SVG` and `path` that is being used. I tried renaming it but it does not work, as I don't get an output, some of the elements just disappear.

Any suggesstions?

Comment: Please reduce your example to a specific snippet for us to examine. The first C in CSS stands for _cascading_, and that's how it's supposed to work. I suggest you look into _load order_, _inheritance_, and _specificity_ to learn how to control which styles are applied in different situations.

Comment: Please stop adding the `[web]` and `[web-deployment]` tags to every question you ask. The first sentence of [tag:web]'s information is "Do not use this tag." It is far too broad a tag to be of any use. We know you're using web technologies by the fact of the other tags, `[javascript]`, `[html]`, and `[css]`. Likewise, [tag:web-deployment]'s information says "The activities that make a website available for use on a remote system." but this question is not about the deployment of these files, just their use.

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know. I will not use these tags going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippets the only thing that seems to be not very specific as `CSS` rule and that could cause a conflict with other rules regarding `svg` or `path` is this one:

```
svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

which could be written, in order not to conflict other `CSS` rules as such:

```
.svg-file.z-logo svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}
```